# How to get natbib aliases also in Bibliography, not only in the text?

Tags: natbib

I wish to use aliases in the bibliography of my thesis.
Particularly, I would like to insert a list of my publications at the front of my thesis, such as:

> Main publications:
>
> [A1] Me, other authors, Nice paper title, ...
>
> [A2] Me, other authors, Even nicer paper title, ...
>
> Side publications:
>
> [B1] Other author, me, et al., Nice paper title,...
>
> [B2] Other author, me, et al., Other cice paper title,...

In the bibliography, I would like to have these publications at the beginning, such as:

> Bibliography
>
> [A1] ...
>
> [A2] ...
>
> [B1] ...
>
> [B2] ...
>
> [1] ...
>
> [2] ...
>
> [3] ...

However, my articles are just cited as usual in the bibliography, like in this example:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @Article{art:apple,
      author  = {Albert Apple and Bertrand Bean},
      title   = {Fancy article},
      journal = {Fancy Journal},
      year    = {2020},
    }
    
    @Article{art:1,
      author  = {Donald Duck},
      title   = {Poor article},
      journal = {Bad Journal},
      year    = {2020},
    }
    
    @Article{art:2,
      author= {Donald Duck},
      title = {Another poor article},
      journal = {Very Bad Journal},
      year = {2020}
    }
    
    @Article{art:3,
      author  = {Donald Duck},
      title   = {A terrible article},
      journal = {Terrible Journal},
      year    = {2020},
    }
    
    \end{filecontents}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
   In this text, I want to use aliases: The first resource is the main resource and should be labelled \defcitealias{art:apple}{[A1]}\citetalias{art:apple} in the text and the bibliography.
    
    Further articles to be cited are \citep{art:1,art:2,art:3}
    
    \bibliography{bib.bib}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image: Example]

As you can see, the main resource that is labelled [A1] in the text, appears as a standard resource [1] in the bibliography. Is there a way to have the aliases also represented in the bibliography?

And a bonus question: Is there also something like \nocite available with aliases? I don't need it here, because the list of my publications will be the first references in the thesis and therefore they are at the top of the bibliography anyway, but it would be nice to know, if there is something like \aliasnocite.

Thank you,
lepakk

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Since you're using the `unsrt` bibliography style -- aside: since you employ the `natib` citation management package, why aren't you using the `unsrtnat` bib style instead? -- you could  simply run `\nocite{art:apple, art:1, art:2, art:3}` immediately after `\begin{document}`, to ensure that these four pieces are listed first in the bibliography. Incidentally, I fear that you may be vastly overestimating your readers' willingness -- or ability -- to care about the distinction between the `[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] ...` and `[A1] [A2] [B1] [B2] [1] [2] ...` numbering schemes.

Comment: To continue the idea expressed in my previous comment, about using `\nocite` with a suitable set of arguments: I think that if you post a quick note immediately before the bibliography, of the form "Items 1 through 3 in the following bibliography list my major publications. Items 4 through 7 list my side publications", will completely satisfy your readers' thirst for knowledge about your major and minor publications. Anything more, such as duplicating a part of the bibliography, may well come across as needless self-aggrandisement. Do you want to risk creating such an impression?

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion to just \nocite all of my publications at the beginning of the document, so they become references 1 to whatever. It will be somehow sufficient. However I am still interested, how one could give an alias for a citation and make this also appear in the bibliography. In the case of some (content-wise) outstandingly important references, I think this is also helpful for the reader to easily distinguish these publication, particularly if there are not just one or two but a few. In that case, I think it is easier to remember [Alias] rather than some random numbers.